# Blob images urls with next.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, blob, nextjs-image

Is there some solution to use blob in next.js ? Previously I used img and blob URL worked well, but now when I'm trying to use Image component blob url doesn't work.

I tried to add blob to domains :

```
domains: ['softflixprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net']
```

but i got error form sever because next Image generate that request URL:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftflixprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net%2Fproduct-covers%2FWindows-10-Pro.webp&w=375&q=75
```

instead of :

```
Request URL: https://softflixprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net/product-covers/Microsoft-Office-2019-Professional.webp
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Avoid posting (link to) images! Post your code and errors in text format instead

Comment: Blob URLs are currently [not supported](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19291) by `next/image`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer you need to do tho things

first: Add to your domains your blob api

```
domains: ['softflixprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net']
```

second: Pass in image special loader which could be very simple

```
const loader = ()=> imgUrl (From blob api)
```

and it should looks like :

```
<Image src={imgUrl} loader={loader} {...otherProps} />
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution for this is to create a custom loader:

```
const customImgLoader = ({ src }) => {
    return `${src}`
}

//later to use

<Image loader={customImgLoader} alt="Avatar" width=64 height=64 src={avatarUrl} />
```

We tell the next/image to return src as it is